# Merging Cells in Multiple Tables Word

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word

Currently using the following code to loop through a table in Word and merge the cells in the first column where the values are the same:

```
  Dim tbl As Word.Table
  Dim cel1 As Word.Cell
  Dim cel2 As Word.Cell
  Dim rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long, i As Long, r As Long

  Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  colIndex = tbl.Columns.Count
  rowIndex = tbl.Rows.Count

  For r = 1 To rowIndex - 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cel1 = tbl.Cell(r, 1)
    Set cel2 = tbl.Cell(r + 1, 1)
    If cel1.Range.Text = cel2.Range.Text Then
     cel2.Range.Text = ""
     cel1.Merge MergeTo:=cel2
     'r = r + 1
    End If
  Next r
```

This works well when there is only one table in the document; however, when there are multiple tables, nothing happens.  I've tried adding a With, but keeps failing on me.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this again, realized that I was missing a With statement.  Revised code works and looks as follows:

```
Sub MergeTest()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim cel1 As Word.Cell
    Dim cel2 As Word.Cell
    Dim rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long, i As Long, r As Long

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    colIndex = tbl.Columns.Count
    rowIndex = tbl.Rows.Count

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
      For r = 1 To rowIndex - 1
       On Error Resume Next
      Set cel1 = tbl.Cell(r, 1)
     Set cel2 = tbl.Cell(r + 1, 1)
        If cel1.Range.Text = cel2.Range.Text Then
         cel2.Range.Text = ""
         cel1.Merge MergeTo:=cel2
        'r = r + 1
        End If
    Next r
    Next
    End Sub
```